# m2eclipse maven-jetty-plugin -Djetty.port=8081 is not being detected

Tags: m2eclipse, maven-jetty-plugin

I have the following as my goal in a m2eclipse run configuration:

jetty:run-exploded -e -Djetty.port=8081

However, the server is still started on 8080. Changing it to -e -Djetty.port=8081 jetty:run-exploded does not help.

This is not a m2eclipse issue. Running mvn -e -Djetty.port=8081 jetty:run-exploded does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pom.xml where you have your jetty plugin specified, check to see if you are using the jettyConfig tag.  That tag allows you to specify configurations for jetty in an xml format http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/jetty.xml for more info.  Anyway, in this config there is a section where you can set a connector and in their you can specify the port.  Also, by configuring it this way you will not have to specify the -Djetty.port=8081 when running the maven command.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just specify the Djetty flag before configuring it, such as `jetty:run-exploded -e -Djetty -Djetty.port=8081` in command line